# monitoring Docker Container

Tags: docker, zabbix

I have Zabbix Running, How can I monitoring Docker container. I have tried more than 50 Google links nothing is working. 
I have to install Zabbix agent on docket host. But I not able see docker container in Zabbix. It don't have any template associated with it

Answer (score 0):

> How can I monitoring Docker container?

That's very generic question. Try to start with https://github.com/monitoringartist/zabbix-docker-monitoring. It provides you also basic template + option to add more your own container metrics, which may meet your Docker container monitoring needs.